# Firefox uploads images sideways

Tags: firefox

When uploading images to Ebay etc firefox rotates the image sideways every time the image is portrait view, this happens immediately in the upload file dialogue box and I cannot find a solution, for Ebay I must be able to upload the images correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**Option one:**

Set Shotwell's preferences to write metadata (like rotation) to the files. Shotwell is a [non-destructive](http://www.yorba.org/shotwell/help/edit-nondestructive.html) editor by default.

Edit/Preferences/ then check the box like below.

[image: Shotwell prefs]

Now, when you rotate the change will be persistent, even on other computers.

**Option two:**

- Open any image from the file browser (you can right-click and choose 'Open With Image Viewer').
- Use the arrow tool on the tool bar to rotate the image.

[image: Image viewer rotate]

- Close the Image Viewer window, you will be prompted to save the change. Do so.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Firefox issue.
When pictures are taken with a digital camera, portrait mode pictures can be stored in two ways:

1. The actual pixel data is rotated so that you have a real portrait image.
2. The pixel data is stored as a landscape image and it's marked in metadata as a portrait.

If your camera does the second then most image viewers detect this, while websites may not.
The best you can do is open your image in an editor and rotate the image there, then save and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but it sounds like the image may be not rotated "right" when you stored it on your computer (this would happen when you turn your camera 90 degrees to take a picture.) In this case, you would need to rotate the image before you upload it. To do this, go to where the image is saved and open it with the image viewer (if it is not the first item on the right click menu, you can do this by right clicking, then going to the open with submenu, and selecting image viewer.) In the image viewer, there should be buttons near the top in the toolbar for rotating the image 90 degrees either way. With my icon theme, they look like a circular arrow with a dot in the middle. Click the correct one, and then close the image viewer. You will be asked if you want to save the changes. Click Save. Your image should now be rotated correctly and you can upload it with firefox.

Comment: thank you for your help, yes I do turn the camera 90 degrees to take the picture, save it to shotwell edit then upload to ebay, it is at this point that the rotation happens. I have just recently moved from windows 7 to ubuntu, with windows os and explorer this never happened, I was able to take the photo and up load keeping the portrait format, if the problem is not fire fox what can i do, also when i take a photo in landscape, then crop the image to a portrait style to suit the content I want it still rotates the image, all help is greatly needed